# Populating a field from a table in phpmyadmin

Tags: enums, phpmyadmin, field, populate

i have a database that i'm currently managing with phpmyadmin

i have 2 tables :

**book (int id, varchar title, varchar category)**

**category(varchar category)**

when inserting a new book, i want  the category to be populated with all the categories in the category table, but i couldn't do it in phpmyadmin. I can only use enum

Comment: Why would you want to copy the data from one table to the other?  If you want to make use of the category table, you would use a JOIN later when you select the data

Comment: the problem is that the category is like an input text, i want is to be like a combobox loaded from category table

Comment: oooh...  What you need to do is call the contents of the category table and create a dropdown, right?  I'll post that.  Give me a few.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what you need to do...
Create a dropdown (select box) in the HTML, with an include for a PHP script that will populate the dropdown (this is PHP in the HTML)

```
print("<select name='car_make_sel' id='car_make_sel'>
    <option value=''>Choose Make</option>");
    include 'includes/[getCategories].php';
print("</select>");
```

In the PHP script, use this:

```
$mysqli= new mysqli($mysql_host, $mysql_user, $mysql_password, $mysql_database);

if($mysqli->connect_errno > 0){
    die('Unable to connect to database [' . $db->connect_error . ']');
}    
$stmt = 'SELECT distinct `car_model` FROM lsc_callRecord order by `car_model`';
$resultMod = $mysqli->query($stmt);
while($rows = $resultMod->fetch_assoc()){
    print("<option value='". $rows['car_model'] ."'>". $rows['car_model'] ."</option>");
}
```

This is all taken from a page where I was populating a select dropdown with models of cars.  You can use this as a template for whatever you're using it for.